# C# - Convert System._COMObject to Date

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, active-directory

I am having a hard time to find a working translation of a System._COMObject to a date i am searching for. I am using this to get the information out of our AD:

```
de.Properties["accountExpires"].Value.ToString();
```

Its value is always System._Comobject, no matter what I tried to convert.
Appreciate help in advance.